# Can a single video be played with changing the formate extention, but not the video itsel

Tags: video-streaming

The reason I ask this is because I notice some interesting results changing the format and playing video on different browsers.

Basically what I want is if I can play Single file video lets say randomtest.mp4 and change that last extension to .ovg and play it directly from that same video file without making a new file. This way I can save space on my website, and not have to upload multiple video formats all I would need is just that one for the standard.

I don't care if I need to use jquery, javascript, php, ect...

If it is possible an example code, or website one or the other would be very appreciated. This way I can know what I need to do and how it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it appears that you equate changing the file extension to changing the video format.

If you simply change the extension of a file you will still be able to play the file if you assume it as the original type. This would not save space if you actually need two separate video formats, in which case you would need two different files anyways.

Most file types have a signature in its internal header. Changing the file extension is essentially changing the file name; not the format.

As you might have experienced, some programs (browsers) associate with certain file types. This is often how it is within operating systems. However, this is just automatic association.